# Find the linear approximation for $w = \frac{gW}{(1+\frac hR)^2}$

Tags: calculus

Find the linear approximation for $h≈0$ for $$w = \frac{gW}{(1+\frac hR)^2}$$, the weight of a satellite at altitude $h$ above the earth's surface, where $W$ is the mass of the satellite on earth's surface and $R$ is the radius of the earth.
could anyone provide some hints, please.
very confused with variables.

Comment: Try ignoring all the variables, and writing down a linear approximation for $w = \frac{1}{(1 + h)^2}$. Can you do that? Your answer should look like $w \approx P + Qh$, where $P$ and $Q$ are some numbers that you'll work out.

Comment: so, is it just $1-2h$?

Comment: Yes. And if you evaluate that at $h/R$ instead of $h$, you get $1 - 2h/R$. Since your function is $gW$ times as big as this one, what will be your approximation?

Comment: $gW(1-2h/R)$, thanks)

Comment: One small suggestion: rewrite as $w \approx gW - \frac{2gW}{R}h$, i.e., in the form $a + b h$, so that the coefficients of the individual terms are clearly evident (since these coeffs are generally the things that have physical meaning: the $gW$ is the weight at height $0$, and the other coeff is how the weight changes with height (to first order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider it as a function of $h$: $$w(h) = \frac{gW}{\left(1+\frac{h}{R}\right)^2}$$Can you find the tangent line at $h = 0$? It is: $$y - w(0) = w'(0)(h-0).$$